# Cannot update a child component on his parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

Well, I'm pretty new with React Native and I'm trying to update a child component on his Parent, the thing is that I'm giving this error (Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component.) and I don't know what to do.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHBca.jpg -> The father component.

```js
const CallList: React.FC<NavigationProps> = (props) => {
  const [absences, setAbsences] = useState<Array<Array<{
    id: number,
    checked: boolean
  }>>>([]);
  // const [absences, setAbsences] = useState([{'id': 0, 'checked': false},{'id': 1, 'checked': false}]);

  const { setOptions } = useNavigation();

  const {aula} = props.route.params;

  const [students, setStudents] = useState<Array<StudentProps>>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const {signOut, docente, anoSemMat} = useAuth();
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeNAw.jpg -> That's the place where I call the Child Component **(StudentsList)**

```js
if (loading || absences.length == 0 || students.length == 0) return <Loading/>;
  else {
    return (
      <>
        <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView} contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1, marginTop: 30}}>
            <SafeAreaView>
              <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
                  <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior = "position">
                    <View style={styles.container}>
                        {students.map((student, idx) => {
                            return <StudentsList
                                      key={student.NRO_ALUNO}
                                      student={student}
                                      value={absences[idx]}
                                      onChange={(classes, nroAluno) => setAbsences(changeAbsenceStudent(classes, nroAluno))}
                                      // onChange={(classes, nroAluno) => setAbsences(classes)}
                                    />
                        })}
                        <Button onPress={() => console.log(absences)} title="click"/>
                    </View>
                  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </ScrollView>
      </>
    );
  }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yq82l.jpg -> The Child Component

```js
interface Students {
    student: StudentsListProps;
    onChange: (classes: Array<{
      id: number,
      checked: boolean
    }>, pos: number) => void;
    value: Array<{
      id: number,
      checked: boolean
    }>
}

interface StudentsState {
    isVisible: boolean,
    checkAll: boolean,
    classes: Array<{
        id: number,
        checked: boolean
    }>,
    student: StudentsListProps
}

export default class StudentsList extends React.Component<Students, StudentsState> {

  constructor(props : Students) {
    super(props)
    const { student, value } = this.props;
    this.state = {
      isVisible: false,
      checkAll: false,
      classes: value,
      student: student
    }
  }
```

All I need is to get the value from StudentsList on CallList but I don't know the best way to do that so I made this "onChange" in StudentsList.

Comment: Could you paste minimal reproducible code? (Not screenshot) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Watanabe.N done

Comment: Please (still) provide minimal reproducible code - we need the full code of your `<CallList>` and `<StudentList>` to be able to help ;) 
Passing callback to children that update the state of the parent is totally ok, but this update is probably triggered at render time. This post may help a lot ;) 
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/18178#issuecomment-602323184